# transfer folder between one drive accounts

Tags: onedrive

I have a folder on my one drive account. I want to get this folder added to a onedrive account of someone else for which I have file editing permissions. How do I do this? I can't even seem to find out how to copy the folder from one drive to my desktop and upload it to the other account, let alone transfer between the 2.